# systemd reboot with shorter timeout?

Tags: systemd

I'd like be able to use systemd to reboot a system nicely at first, but with a pretty short timeout which, if exceeded, forces a reboot (perhaps with something like `/proc/sysrq-trigger`). It looked like all the pieces were there do this. I made a target that looks like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=My Forceful Reboot
DefaultDependencies=no
Requires=systemd-reboot.service
After=systemd-reboot.service
AllowIsolate=yes
JobTimeoutSec=30s
JobTimeoutAction=reboot-immediate
```

I could start or isolate this target and the system would attempt a graceful reboot and force a reboot if needed. It doesn't appear to work and it's been tricky to debug. I'm able to reboot the machine in other ways, and `journalctl` shows that services are being shutdown, but the reboot never happens.

Also, if `reboot-immediate` (which seems to use the `reboot(2)` system call) isn't forceful enough, can I somehow use `/proc/sysrq-trigger`?

Thanks for any help,